# Scheduling in Asp.net Mvc and web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project with Asp.net MVC 5 and web api and SQL Server. I should implement a functionality that required scheduling.

I have some users in this system that every user can register an order and I save order information in the database.

**Problem:** for each order that has been registered in system after 2 minutes, I should send a message to his owner and notify him about his order status.

How should I check each order status 2 minutes after it has been registered?

Should I schedule a task per order that has been registered? (it could be more than 500 order per sec so I don't thinks it is a good solution)

I want a solution to handle this with a good performance.

Comment: https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: Or [quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: @S.Akbari,@Peter Bons I know these components but should i schedule a task per order that has been registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best solution here is [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Hangfire is built for these kind of challenges. It really doesn't matter how many jobs you have. After you have configured Hangfire you can simply pass methods to the queue. You can also delay the execution with a TimeSpan

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
() => Console.WriteLine("Delayed!"),
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

You can even chain jobs, very handy if you have multiple steps in your order process:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => {

    SomeProcessToComplete();

},TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

static void SomeProcessToComplete(){

     //after code runs add another job to the queue
    BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Delayed!"),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
}
```

Comment: my app is not a console app its a web application an is running on IIS and it may stop app when no request come to app for long time

Comment: Thats what its for :). It will keep itself alive. I have used it for years and never missed a task

Comment: What you can do though is set the IdleTimeout to 0 in the applicationpool advanced settings on your IIS server

Answer (score 0):

another solution could be ,each time order is saved write it to a text file on server,and at the same time add watch to notify you the text file is changed ,which will trigger your service to send message

Comment: using a database table to store the information about the orders would be a lot more robust and scalable (think when lots of people are doing it near-simultaneously), but yeah offloading to a separate background service is a very common way to implement this kind of feature.